# Overloading Numpy functions?

Tags: python, numpy, overloading

I am hoping for some clarification on overloading Numpy universal functions in class methods.

To illustrate, here is a class `myreal` with an overloaded `cos` method.  This overloaded method calls `cos` imported from the math module.

```
from math import cos

class myreal:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
        
    def cos(self):
        return self.__class__(cos(self.x))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.x.__str__()
                
x = myreal(3.14)
y = myreal.cos(x)
print(x,y)
```

This works as expected and results in values

```
3.14 -0.9999987317275395
```

And, as expected, simply trying

```
z = cos(x)
```

results in an error `TypeError: must be real number, not myreal`, since outside of the `myreal` class, `cos` expects a float argument.

But surprisingly (and here is my question), if I now import `cos` from numpy, I can call `cos(x)` as a function, rather than as a method of the `myreal` class.  In other words, this now works:

```
from numpy import cos
z = cos(x)
```

So it seems that the `myreal.cos()` method is now able to overload the Numpy global function `cos(x)`.   Is this "multipledispatch" behavior included by design?

Checking the type of the Numpy `cos(x)` reveals that it is of type `numpy.ufunc', which suggests an explanation involving Numpy universal functions.

Any clarification about what is going on here  would be very interesting and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.cos` given a numeric dtype array (or anything that becomes that):

```
In [246]: np.cos(np.array([1,2,np.pi]))
Out[246]: array([ 0.54030231, -0.41614684, -1.        ])
```

But if I give it an object dtype array, I get an error:

```
In [248]: np.cos(np.array([1,2,np.pi,None]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cos'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [248], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.cos(np.array([1,2,np.pi,None]))

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable cos method
```

With the `None` element the array is `object` dtype:

```
In [249]: np.array([1,2,np.pi,None])
Out[249]: array([1, 2, 3.141592653589793, None], dtype=object)
```

`ufunc` when given an object dtype array, iterates through the array and tries to use each element's "method".  For something like `np.add`, it looks for the `.__add__` method.  For functions like `cos` (and `exp` and `sqrt`) it looks for a method of the same name.  Usually this fails because most objects don't have a `cos` method.  In your case, it didn't fail - because you defined a `cos` method.

Try `np.sin` to see the error.

I wouldn't call this `overloading`.  It's just a quirk of how `numpy` handles object dtype arrays.

Comment: Fantastic explanation.  Should this "quirk" be exploited to define, say, a new numeric data type with functions cos, sin, etc?  Or is there a better way to get function-like behavior for elementary functions?

Answer (score 1):

`myreal.cos` is not able to overload the numpy `cos`. You are calling the `numpy` `cos` all the time, except inside `myreal` or when you write `myreal.cos`. It seems that numpy functions are friendly, and when `numpy cos` receives an object it doesn't know, instead of an error message, it tries to call `cos` on the object.

```
from numpy import cos

class myreal:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        
    def cos(self, myarg=None):
        print(f'myreal-cos myarg: {myarg}')
        return f'myreal-cos-{self.x}'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.x.__str__()
```

Now when we run cos, it's numpy cos, not ours:

```
cos(5)
0.28366218546322625
```

Let's try to use `myarg`:

```
cos(5, myarg='a')

TypeError: cos() got an unexpected keyword argument 'myarg'
```

It's still `numpy cos`, so it doesn't know the myarg keyword.

```
cos(myreal(2))
myreal-cos args: None
'myreal-cos-2'
```

This works, because `numpy cos` calls our `myreal.cos`. But it doesn't work with the myarg keyword.

If we try `sin`:

```
sin(myreal(2))
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type myreal which has no callable sin method
```

This error message seems to make sense. `numpy sin` tries to call `myreal sin`, but it doesn't exist.

This friendly feature is useful when we create an array:

```
A = np.array([myreal(i) for i in range(4)])
array([[<__main__.myreal object at 0x7fc8c9429cf0>,
        <__main__.myreal object at 0x7fc8c939b970>],
       [<__main__.myreal object at 0x7fc8c939b0a0>,
        <__main__.myreal object at 0x7fc8c939a8c0>]], dtype=object)
```

Let's call our `myreal.cos` function on that array:

```
myreal.cos(A)

----> 9     return f'myreal-cos-{self.x}'
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'x'
```

It doesn't work, because we didn't prepare our function to work on arrays. But `numpy.cos` can, and for each element in the array it will call our `myreal.cos`:

```
cos(A)
myreal-cos myarg: None
myreal-cos myarg: None
myreal-cos myarg: None
myreal-cos myarg: None
array(['myreal-cos-0', 'myreal-cos-1', 'myreal-cos-2', 'myreal-cos-3'],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: Cool explanation -thanks.  Nice that the myreal.cos() "method" can handle arrays arrays of myreals.   Is this a feature that should be exploited?   Or, as the post above suggests, just a quirk of Numpy?

Answer (score 0):

The answers above both clarified my misunderstanding.  Basically, a quirk in Numpy is what gives the impression that `myreal` class methods `cos`, `sin` etc are "overloading" the Numpy functions `cos`, `sin` and so on.

Rather than exploiting this quirk in Numpy, however, it seems the more correct way to overload the `cos` function so it accepts a `myreal` is to use the singledispatch mechanism.

My original class definitions remain unchanged, but a "cos" function is added to a dispatch registery that is searched when looking for the appropriate function/argument to call.

```
from functools import singledispatch

class myreal:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
        
    def cos(self):
        return myreal(cos(self.x))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.x.__str__()
    
@singledispatch
def cos(x):
    import math
    return math.cos(x)

cos.register(myreal,myreal.cos);
print(cos.registry.keys())

x = myreal(3.14)
y = cos(x)
print(y)
```

The output is :

```
dict_keys([<class 'object'>, <class '__main__.myreal'>])
-0.9999987317275395
```

This also removes a dependence on Numpy (it if it not needed).

Here is a version of the above that uses Numpy arrays (inspired by @AndrzejO, above).

```
from functools import singledispatch
from numpy import array

class myreal:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
        
    def cos(self):
        return self.__class__(cos(self.x))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
                
    def __str__(self):
        return self.x.__str__()
    
@singledispatch
def cos(x):
    import numpy
    return numpy.cos(x)

cos.register(myreal,myreal.cos);

x = array([myreal(i) for i in range(5)])
y = cos(x)
print(y)
```

The output is :

```
[1.0 0.5403023058681398 -0.4161468365471424 -0.9899924966004454
 -0.6536436208636119]
```

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: As @AndrejO pointed out, I could have implemented the Numpy version without using singledispatch  decorator and registries.  Numpy would simply look for appropriate methods for elements in a Numpy array.  But the above could be useful for those functions not already defined by Numpy.